# Subclassing UILabel doesn't work as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want to add a `UILabel` to the view which slides down when an error occurs to send the error message to user and after 3 seconds it will slide up to disappear. The prototype of it is like the one Facebook or Instagram shows. I need `errorLabel` in many `ViewController`s, so I tried to subclass `UILabel`. Here is my subclass `ErrorLabel`:

```
class ErrorLabel: UILabel {
    var errorString: String?

    func sendErrorMessage() {
        self.text = errorString

        showErrorLabel()
        let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: "hideErrorLabel", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    func animateFrameChange() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { self.layoutIfNeeded() }, completion: nil)
    }
    func showErrorLabel() {
        let oldFrame = self.frame
        let newFrame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, oldFrame.origin.y, oldFrame.height + 30, oldFrame.width)
        self.frame = newFrame
        self.animateFrameChange()
    }
    func hideErrorLabel() {
        let oldFrame = self.frame
        let newFrame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, oldFrame.origin.y, oldFrame.height - 30, oldFrame.width)
        self.frame = newFrame
        self.animateFrameChange()
    }
}
```

Then, I tried to add the `errorLabel` to one of my `ViewController` like following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var errorLabel = ErrorLabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let errorLabelFrame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.width, 0)
        self.errorLabel.frame = errorLabelFrame
        self.errorLabel.backgroundColor = translucentTurquoise
        self.errorLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18)
        self.errorLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.errorLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        self.view.addSubview(errorLabel)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(errorLabel)
    }

    func aFunc(errorString: String) {
        self.errorLabel.errorString = errorString
        self.errorLabel.sendErrorMessage()
    }
}
```

When I run it in iOS Simulator, it doesn't work as expected:

1. `errorLabel` shows on the left horizontally and in the middle vertically with only `I...` which should be `Invalid parameters`.
2. After 1 second, it goes to the position as expected but its width is still not `self.view.frame.width`.
3. After that, nothing happens but it should slide up after 3 seconds.

Can you tell me what's wrong and how to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

I might have partial solution to your issues. Hope it helps.

- The `I...`  happens when the string is longer than the view. For this you'll need to increase the size of `UILabel`.
- For aligning text inside a UILable refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel?rq=1).
- To animate away use the same  code in the completion block of the `UIView.animateWithDuration`. Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086753/uiview-animates-away-on-timer)

I suggest you to consider using `Extensions` to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than subclassing UILabel I would subclass UIViewController, which maybe you have aldready done? Let's call out subclass - BaseViewController and let all our UIViewControllers subclass this class.

I would then programatically create an UIView which contains a vertically and horizontally centered UILabel inside this BaseViewController class. The important part here is to create NSLayoutConstraints for it. I would then hide and show it by changing the values of the constraints.

I would use the excellent [pod](https://cocoapods.org/) named [Cartography](https://github.com/robb/Cartography) to create constraints, which makes it super easy and clean!

With this solution you should be able to show or hide an error message in any of your UIViewControllers

This is **untested code** but hopefully very near a solution to your problem.

```
import Cartography /* Requires that you have included Cartography in your Podfile */
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    private var yPositionForErrorViewWhenVisible: Int { return 0 }
    private var yPositionForErrorViewWhenInvisible: Int { return -50 }
    private let hideDelay: NSTimeInterval = 3
    private var timer: NSTimer!

    var yConstraintForErrorView: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var errorView: UIView!
    var errorLabel: UILabel!

    //MARK: - Initialization
    required init(aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    //MARK: - Private Methods
    private func setup() {
        setupErrorView()
    }

    private func setupErrorView() {
        errorView = UIView()
        errorLabel = UILabel()

        errorView.addSubview(errorLabel)
        view.addSubview(errorView)

        /* Set constraints between viewController and errorView and errorLabel */
        layout(view, errorView, errorLabel) {
            parent, errorView, errorLabel in

            errorView.width == parent.width
            errorView.centerX == parent.centerX
            errorView.height == 50

            /* Capture the y constraint, which defaults to be 50 points out of screen, so that it is not visible */
            self.yConstraintForErrorView = (errorView.top == parent.top - self.yPositionForErrorViewWhenInvisible)

            errorLabel.height = 30
            errorLabel.width == errorView.width
            errorLabel.centerX == errorView.centerX
            errorLabel.centerY = errorView.centerY
        }
    }

    private func hideOrShowErrorMessage(hide: Bool, animated: Bool) {
         if hide {
            yConstraintForErrorView.constant = yPositionForErrorViewWhenInvisible
        } else {
            yConstraintForErrorView.constant = yPositionForErrorViewWhenVisible
        }

        let automaticallyHideErrorViewClosure: () -> Void = {
            /* Only scheduling hiding of error message, if we just showed it. */
            if show {
                automaticallyHideErrorMessage()
            }
        }

        if animated {
            view.animateConstraintChange(completion: {
                (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                automaticallyHideErrorViewClosure()
            })
        } else {
            view.layoutIfNeeded()
            automaticallyHideErrorViewClosure()
        }
    }

    private func automaticallyHideErrorMessage() {
        if timer != nil {
            if timer.valid {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
            timer = nil
        }
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(hideDelay, target: self, selector: "hideErrorMessage", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)    
    }

    //MARK: - Internal Methods
    func showErrorMessage(message: String, animated: Bool = true) {
        errorLabel.text = message
        hideOrShowErrorMessage(false, animated: animated)
    }

    //MARK: - Selector Methods
    func hideErrorMessage(animated: Bool = true) {
        hideOrShowErrorMessage(true, animated: animated)
    }
}

extension UIView {

    static var standardDuration: NSTimeInterval { return 0.3 }

    func animateConstraintChange(duration: NSTimeInterval = standardDuration, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
        UIView.animate(durationUsed: duration, animations: {
            () -> Void in
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: completion)
    }
}
```